# Refactoring JavaScript / TypeScript: Avoiding repeating properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, null, refactoring

EDIT: Existing answers are 2 and 5 years old (from 2017 and 2014).

How can I shorten the following statement

```
  ratingsExisting(): boolean {
    return (
      this.fromAPIData.book &&
      this.fromAPIData.book.misc &&
      this.fromAPIData.book.misc.ratings &&
      this.fromAPIData.book.misc.ratings.length > 0
    );
  }
```

so that I don't receive errors if any of the properties is `null`?

Comment: Read this article about [Optional Chaining in TypeScript](https://medium.com/inside-rimeto/optional-chaining-in-typescript-622c3121f99b)

Comment: You are a bit to early ... `this.fromAPIData?.book?.misc` will hopefully be part of both JS and TS soon ... till then you have to fall back to other syntactic sugars shown in the dupe.

Comment: Checking that each of these properties exist can be accomplished with the Underscore library.  So _.has(this.fromAPIData, 'book.misc.ratings.length)